# Open device camera only after firing intent for opening camera

Tags: java, android, c++, android-intent, android-camera

I have a scenario in which I fire a intent to open camera through following code.

```
if(isCameraInUse())
            return;
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mImageFile = getOutputFromCamera();
Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(mImageFile);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempuri);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

Now if I have more than one camera app, then I see all of them as option to open. But I want device camera only to be opened. Is this possible? Is it possible to fire an intent specify which app should catch that intent?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create an object of android.hardware.Camera. And simply calling open method of it will do the work for you.

Calling open() method on that `Camera camera = Camera.open();` it will create a new Camera object to access a particular hardware camera. If the same camera is opened by other applications, this will throw a RuntimeException.

You may use this in your code before

`Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` Hope this helps. I believe that you have added these in your application's manifest.

```html
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch a specific application use this code. I hope it will solve your problem.

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("camera package name");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setPackage on the Intent

```
i.setPackage("package.name"); 
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.camera");
```

Call the camera by the package name think it should help.